Mongo Rest Server
Using the server architecture to provide a REST interface. So I can send/recieve JSON that is put/retrieved from a mongo server.
The Fir class MongoRest is similar in style to the WebServer I just posted. The MongoServer class builds on some code I previously posted here to accesses a Mongo DB.
MongoRest.cpp (includes main)
#include "MongoServer.h"
#include "NisseServer/NisseServer.h"
#include "NisseServer/PyntControl.h"
#include "NisseHTTP/HTTPHandler.h"
#include "NisseHTTP/Request.h"
#include "NisseHTTP/Response.h"
#include <ThorsSocket/Server.h>
#include <filesystem>


namespace TASock    = ThorsAnvil::ThorsSocket;
namespace TANS      = ThorsAnvil::Nisse::Server;
namespace TANH      = ThorsAnvil::Nisse::HTTP;
namespace MRest     = ThorsAnvil::Nisse::Examples::MongoRest;
namespace FS        = std::filesystem;

class MongoRest: public TANS::NisseServer
{
    TANH::HTTPHandler       http;
    TANS::PyntControl       control;
    MRest::MongoServer&     mongoServer;

    TASock::ServerInit getServerInit(std::optional<FS::path> certPath, int port)
    {
        if (!certPath.has_value()) {
            return TASock::ServerInfo{port};
        }

        TASock::CertificateInfo     certificate{FS::canonical(FS::path(*certPath) /= "fullchain.pem"),
                                                FS::canonical(FS::path(*certPath) /= "privkey.pem")
                                               };
        TASock::SSLctx              ctx{TASock::SSLMethodType::Server, certificate};
        return TASock::SServerInfo{port, std::move(ctx)};
    }

    public:
        MongoRest(int poolSize, int port, std::optional<FS::path> certPath, MRest::MongoServer& ms)
            : TANS::NisseServer(poolSize)
            , control(*this)
            , mongoServer(ms)
        {
            // CRUD Person Interface
            http.addPath(TANH::Method::POST,   "/person/",        [&](TANH::Request& request, TANH::Response& response) {mongoServer.personCreate(request, response);});
            http.addPath(TANH::Method::GET,    "/person/Id-{id}", [&](TANH::Request& request, TANH::Response& response) {mongoServer.personGet(request, response);});
            http.addPath(TANH::Method::PUT,    "/person/Id-{id}", [&](TANH::Request& request, TANH::Response& response) {mongoServer.personUpdate(request, response);});
            http.addPath(TANH::Method::DELETE, "/person/Id-{id}", [&](TANH::Request& request, TANH::Response& response) {mongoServer.personDelete(request, response);});

            // Search Person Interface
            http.addPath(TANH::Method::GET,    "/person/findByName/{first}/{last}",[&](TANH::Request& request, TANH::Response& response) {mongoServer.personFindByName(request, response);});
            http.addPath(TANH::Method::GET,    "/person/findByTel/{tel}",          [&](TANH::Request& request, TANH::Response& response) {mongoServer.personFindByTel(request, response);});
            http.addPath(TANH::Method::GET,    "/person/findByZip/{zip}",          [&](TANH::Request& request, TANH::Response& response) {mongoServer.personFindByZip(request, response);});

            listen(getServerInit(certPath, port), http);
            listen(TASock::ServerInfo{port+2}, control);
        }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc != 6 && argc != 7)
    {
        std::cerr << "Usage: MongoRest <port> <MongoHost> <MongoUser> <MongoPass> <MongoDB> [<certificateDirectory>]\n";
        return 1;
    }
    try
    {
        int                     port        = std::stoi(argv[1]);
        std::string             mongoHost   = argv[2];
        std::string             mongoUser   = argv[3];
        std::string             mongoPass   = argv[4];
        std::string             mongoDB     = argv[5];
        std::optional<FS::path> certPath;
        if (argc == 7) {
            certPath = FS::canonical(argv[6]);
        }

        static constexpr int poolSize             = 6;
        static constexpr int mongoConnectionCount = 12;
        std::cout << "Nisse MongoRest: Port: " << port << " MongoHost: >" << mongoHost << "< Mongo User: >" << mongoUser << "< MongoPass: >" << mongoPass << "< MongoDB: >" << mongoDB << "< Certificate Path: >" << (argc == 6 ? "NONE" : argv[6]) << "<\n";

        MRest::MongoServer  mongoServer{mongoConnectionCount, mongoHost, 27017, mongoUser, mongoPass, mongoDB};
        MongoRest           server{poolSize, port, certPath, mongoServer};
        server.run();
    }
    catch (std::exception const& e)
    {
        std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
        throw;
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        std::cerr << "Exception: Unknown\n";
        throw;
    }
}

MongoServer.h
#ifndef THORSANVIL_NISSE_EXAMPLES_MONGO_SERVER_H
#define THORSANVIL_NISSE_EXAMPLES_MONGO_SERVER_H

#include "MongoConnectionPool.h"
#include "NisseHTTP/Request.h"
#include "NisseHTTP/Response.h"
#include "ThorsMongo/ThorsMongo.h"

namespace NHTTP     = ThorsAnvil::Nisse::HTTP;
namespace TAMongo   = ThorsAnvil::DB::Mongo;

namespace ThorsAnvil::Nisse::Examples::MongoRest
{

class MongoServer
{
    MongoConnectionPool     mongoPool;
    public:
        MongoServer(int poolSize, std::string const& host, int port, std::string const& user, std::string const& password, std::string const& db);
        // CRUD
        void personCreate(NHTTP::Request& request, NHTTP::Response& response);
        void personGet(NHTTP::Request& request, NHTTP::Response& response);
        void personUpdate(NHTTP::Request& request, NHTTP::Response& response);
        void personDelete(NHTTP::Request& request, NHTTP::Response& response);

        // FIND
        void personFindByName(NHTTP::Request& request, NHTTP::Response& response);
        void personFindByTel(NHTTP::Request& request, NHTTP::Response& response);
        void personFindByZip(NHTTP::Request& request, NHTTP::Response& response);
    private:
        TAMongo::ObjectID   getIdFromRequest(NHTTP::Request& request);
        void                requestFailed(NHTTP::Response& response, std::initializer_list<std::string> messages);
};

}

#endif

MongoServer.cpp
#include "MongoServer.h"
#include "ThorsMongo/MongoUtil.h"
#include "NisseServer/AsyncStream.h"
#include "ThorSerialize/Traits.h"
#include "ThorSerialize/JsonThor.h"
#include <ranges>


using namespace ThorsAnvil::Nisse::Examples::MongoRest;
namespace TAMongo   = ThorsAnvil::DB::Mongo;
namespace TANS      = ThorsAnvil::Nisse::Server;
namespace TAJson    = ThorsAnvil::Serialize;

// Structures for data stored in the AddressBook collection of the DB.
struct Address
{
    std::string         street1;
    std::string         street2;
    std::string         city;
    std::string         state;
    std::string         zip;
};

struct Telephone
{
    std::string         type;
    std::string         number;
};

struct ContactInfo
{
    Address             address;
    Telephone           telephone;
};

struct Name
{
    std::string         first;
    std::string         last;
};

struct Person
{
    TAMongo::ObjectID   _id;
    Name                name;
    int                 age;
    ContactInfo         contactInfo;
};

// Declarations for the Serializer code.
// This allows JSON and BSON to be coded and decoded into the above classes.
ThorsAnvil_MakeTrait(Address,       street1, street2, city, state, zip);
ThorsAnvil_MakeTrait(Telephone,     type, number);
ThorsAnvil_MakeTrait(ContactInfo,   address, telephone);
ThorsAnvil_MakeTrait(Name,          first, last);
ThorsAnvil_MakeTrait(Person,        _id, name, age, contactInfo);

// Declarations to create Field accesses objects.
// The field access objects are used to create MONGO expressiones.
ThorsMongo_CreateFieldAccess(Person, _id);
ThorsMongo_CreateFieldAccess(Person, name, first);
ThorsMongo_CreateFieldAccess(Person, name, last);
ThorsMongo_CreateFieldAccess(Person, contactInfo, telephone, number);
ThorsMongo_CreateFieldAccess(Person, contactInfo, address, zip);

// Create Very Simple expressions to compare objects on the Mongo DB.
// All of these use the `Eq` class to compare for equality.
// They use the field access objects declared above.
using FindById      = ThorsMongo_FilterFromAccess(Eq, Person, _id);
using FindByFName   = ThorsMongo_FilterFromAccess(Eq, Person, name, first);
using FindByLName   = ThorsMongo_FilterFromAccess(Eq, Person, name, last);
using FindByName    = TAMongo::QueryOp::And<FindByFName, FindByLName>;
using FindByTel     = ThorsMongo_FilterFromAccess(Eq, Person, contactInfo, telephone, number);
using FindByZip     = ThorsMongo_FilterFromAccess(Eq, Person, contactInfo, address, zip);

void MongoServer::requestFailed(NHTTP::Response& response, std::initializer_list<std::string> messages)
{
    response.setStatus(404);

    NHTTP::HeaderResponse   headers;
    for (auto const& message: messages) {
        headers.add("Error", message);
    }
    response.addHeaders(headers);
}

void requestStreamRange(NHTTP::Response& response, TAMongo::FindRange<Person>& result)
{
    std::ostream& output = response.body(NHTTP::Encoding::Chunked);
    output << '[';
    std::string sep = "";
    for (auto const& p: result)
    {
        output << sep << TAJson::jsonExporter(p);
        sep = ", ";
    }
    utput << ']';
}

MongoServer::MongoServer(int poolSize, std::string const& host, int port, std::string const& user, std::string const& password, std::string const& db)
    : mongoPool(poolSize, host, port, user, password, db)
{}

TAMongo::ObjectID MongoServer::getIdFromRequest(NHTTP::Request& request)
{
    TAMongo::ObjectID   result;

    std::stringstream   ss(std::move(request.variables()["id"]));
    ss >> TAJson::jsonImporter(result);

    return result;
}

void MongoServer::personCreate(NHTTP::Request& request, NHTTP::Response& response)
{
    TAMongo::ThorsMongo&    mongo = mongoPool.getConnection();
    TANS::AsyncStream       async(mongo.getStream().getSocket(), request.getContext(), TANS::EventType::Write);
    Person                  person;
    request.body() >> TAJson::jsonImporter(person);

    auto result = mongo["test"]["AddressBook"].insert(std::tie(person));
    if (!result) {
        return requestFailed(response, {result.getHRErrorMessage()});
    }

    response.body(NHTTP::Encoding::Chunked) << TAJson::jsonExporter(result);
}

void MongoServer::personGet(NHTTP::Request& request, NHTTP::Response& response)
{
    TAMongo::ThorsMongo&    mongo = mongoPool.getConnection();
    TANS::AsyncStream       async(mongo.getStream().getSocket(), request.getContext(), TANS::EventType::Write);
    TAMongo::ObjectID       id  = getIdFromRequest(request);

    auto range = mongo["test"]["AddressBook"].find<Person>(FindById{id});
    if (!range) {
        return requestFailed(response, {range.getHRErrorMessage()});
    }

    for (auto const& person: range)
    {
        response.body(NHTTP::Encoding::Chunked) << TAJson::jsonExporter(person);
        return;
    }

    // Only get here if there are no items in the range.
    requestFailed(response, {"No Value Found"});
}

void MongoServer::personUpdate(NHTTP::Request& request, NHTTP::Response& response)
{
    TAMongo::ThorsMongo&    mongo = mongoPool.getConnection();
    TANS::AsyncStream       async(mongo.getStream().getSocket(), request.getContext(), TANS::EventType::Write);
    TAMongo::ObjectID       id  = getIdFromRequest(request);
    Person                  person;
    request.body() >> TAJson::jsonImporter(person);

    auto result = mongo["test"]["AddressBook"].findAndReplaceOne<Person>(FindById{id}, person);
    if (!result) {
        return requestFailed(response, {result.getHRErrorMessage()});
    }

    if (!result.value)
    {
        // No original value.
        response.body(NHTTP::Encoding::Chunked) << "{}";
    }
    else
    {
        // This was the value we replaced.
        response.body(NHTTP::Encoding::Chunked) << TAJson::jsonExporter(*result.value);
    }
}

void MongoServer::personDelete(NHTTP::Request& request, NHTTP::Response& response)
{
    TAMongo::ThorsMongo&    mongo = mongoPool.getConnection();
    TANS::AsyncStream       async(mongo.getStream().getSocket(), request.getContext(), TANS::EventType::Write);
    TAMongo::ObjectID       id  = getIdFromRequest(request);

    auto result = mongo["test"]["AddressBook"].findAndRemoveOne<Person>(FindById{id});
    if (!result) {
        return requestFailed(response, {result.getHRErrorMessage()});
    }

    if (!result.value)
    {
        // No original value.
        response.body(NHTTP::Encoding::Chunked) << "{}";
    }
    else
    {
        // This was the value we removed.
        response.body(NHTTP::Encoding::Chunked) << TAJson::jsonExporter(*result.value);
    }
}

void MongoServer::personFindByName(NHTTP::Request& request, NHTTP::Response& response)
{
    TAMongo::ThorsMongo&    mongo = mongoPool.getConnection();
    TANS::AsyncStream       async(mongo.getStream().getSocket(), request.getContext(), TANS::EventType::Write);
    std::string             first = request.variables()["first"];
    std::string             last  = request.variables()["last"];

    TAMongo::FindRange<Person> result;
    

    if (first == "" && last == "")
    {
        response.setStatus(400);
    }
    if (first == "")
    {
        result = mongo["test"]["AddressBook"].find<Person>(FindByLName{last});
    }
    else if (last == "")
    {
        result = mongo["test"]["AddressBook"].find<Person>(FindByFName{first});
    }
    else
    {
        result = mongo["test"]["AddressBook"].find<Person>(FindByName{first, last});
    }

    if (!result)
    {
        return requestFailed(response, {result.getHRErrorMessage()});
    }

    requestStreamRange(response, result);
}

void MongoServer::personFindByTel(NHTTP::Request& request, NHTTP::Response& response)
{
    TAMongo::ThorsMongo&    mongo = mongoPool.getConnection();
    TANS::AsyncStream       async(mongo.getStream().getSocket(), request.getContext(), TANS::EventType::Write);
    std::string             tel = request.variables()["tel"];

    auto result = mongo["test"]["AddressBook"].find<Person>(FindByTel{tel});
    if (!result) {
        return requestFailed(response, {result.getHRErrorMessage()});
    }

    requestStreamRange(response, result);
}

void MongoServer::personFindByZip(NHTTP::Request& request, NHTTP::Response& response)
{
    TAMongo::ThorsMongo&    mongo = mongoPool.getConnection();
    TANS::AsyncStream       async(mongo.getStream().getSocket(), request.getContext(), TANS::EventType::Write);
    std::string             tel = request.variables()["zip"];

    auto result = mongo["test"]["AddressBook"].find<Person>(FindByZip{tel});
    if (!result) {
        return requestFailed(response, {result.getHRErrorMessage()});
    }

    requestStreamRange(response, result);
}

